# How to Expose Delta Table Data or Synapse Table to Rest API Service using Java/python

Tags: python, java, web-services, azure-databricks, delta-lake

We would like to expose the data from delta table or synapse table to REST API service which is java based or either python language. kindly provide sample for java or python to kick start my new implementation.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have delta table and needs to export the restful API service, in this case, how do we handle

Comment: What do you mean by `export the restful API service`? Provide an example

Comment: yes, exactly. how do we do this API , if possible small hello world example would be fine or guidelines

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could get desired results by following either of the below mentioned ways.

#### WAY -1 (Databricks SQL statement execution)

You can retrieve the delta table data using SQL statement through REST API. Below is the sample cod ethat was working for me.

```
import requests

my_json = {"statement": "select * from delta.`/FileStore/<YOUR_FILE_PATh>`", "warehouse_id": "<YOUR_WAREHOURSE_ID>"}

auth = {"Authorization": "Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>"}

response = requests.post('https://<DATABRICKS_WORKSPACE_URL>/api/2.0/sql/statements', json = my_json, headers=auth).json()

print(response['result']['data_array'])
```

Results:

[image]

#### WAY -2 (DBFS API)

Using DBFS API I'm trying to list the files inside the folder and then appending each .parquet files' data inside dataframe where I'm storing the whole dataframe inside a CSV file. Below is the complete code that's working for me.

```
import requests
import base64
import tempfile
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd

url = "https://<DATABRICKS_WORKSPACE_URL>/api/2.0/dbfs"

folder_path = "/FileStore/<YOUR_FOLDER_PATH>"

access_token = "<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>"

headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}

params = {"path": folder_path}

# Lists folders in Databricks DBFS Folder
response = requests.get(url+'/list', headers=headers,params=params)
files = response.json()

final_df = None

for i in files['files'][1:]:
    params = {"path":i['path']}
    
    # Reads files individually 
    response = requests.get(url+'/read', headers=headers,params=params)
    sample=base64.b64decode(response.json()['data'])

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
        f.write(sample)
        f.seek(0)
        parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(f.name)
        
        df = parquet_file.read().to_pandas()
        
        if(final_df is None):
            final_df=df
        else:
            final_df = pd.concat([df, final_df])
            
final_df.to_csv("example.csv", index=False)
```

Results:

[image]